# WinPE diskpart can't attach vdisk

Tags: vhd, windows-pe, diskpart

I created WinPE 3.0 and didn't modify it in any way. I want to attach a vdisk (.vhd file) while running WinPE but I can't attach it, no error is shown, no indication that diskpart didn't attach it, it just doesn't happen.

These are the steps that I followed:

- WinPE booted
- (i typed the following)
- `diskpart`
- `select vdisk file=e:\myfile.vhd`
- `attach vdisk`

The only thing that happens is the help is shown.

The file is in place, I checked a couple of times, diskpart doesn't give anything useful.

Comment: Does `list vol` inside `diskpart` show the virtual disk?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `assign` as well in diskpart otherwise it will be mounted but not have a drive letter.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/7/archive/2009/10/08/diskpart-exe-and-managing-virtual-hard-disks-vhds-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: i know that i need to assign it, but when i type "select vdisk" it doesn't say an error or drive selected it prints out the help for select (like i typed "select /?"), when i type attach vdisk the same typing it prints out the help without any error...

Comment: I was able to succesfully do it with the commands listed above.

However, I had to move the VHD to a local fixed disk otherwise I was getting "requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation"

Try moving the vhd to a fixed disk location and if it works there, start trying other places.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgotten the quotes on both sides of the filename try that and see if that works for you should look like this 
`SELECT VDISK FILE="C:\Example\Exam22.vhd"`. Do not forget to use quotes on both sides of the complete path.  And when you attach it using the `[attach
 Vdisk file name=<"xxxxx">]`